# ValueError: Shapes (None, 8) and (None, 3) are incompatible

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

**Sorry for my bad english**
I have this error    ValueError: Shapes (None, 8) and (None, 3) are incompatible
And this is my model

```
    num_of_classes = get_num_of_classes()
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(16, (2,2), input_shape=(image_x, image_y, 1), activation='relu') )
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(5, 5), strides=(5, 5), padding='same'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(num_of_classes, activation='softmax'))
    tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-2)
    sgd = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-2)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Finally error in this

```
    with open("train_images", "rb") as f:
        train_images = np.array(pickle.load(f))
    with open("train_labels", "rb") as f:
        train_labels = np.array(pickle.load(f), dtype=np.int32)

    with open("val_images", "rb") as f:
        val_images = np.array(pickle.load(f))
    with open("val_labels", "rb") as f:
        val_labels = np.array(pickle.load(f), dtype=np.int32)

    train_images = np.reshape(train_images, (train_images.shape[0], image_x, image_y, 1))
    val_images = np.reshape(val_images, (val_images.shape[0], image_x, image_y, 1))
    train_labels = np_utils.to_categorical(train_labels)
    val_labels = np_utils.to_categorical(val_labels)
    model, callbacks_list = cnn_model()
    model.summary()
    print(model.summary())

    --> model.fit(train_images, train_labels, validation_data=(val_images, val_labels), epochs=15, batch_size=500, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Comment: Check the shape of `train_labels` vs `num_of_classes`

Comment: Thanks for your comment !. This is the shape train_labels : (71, 8) , and num_of_classes = 2 .

Comment: Well.... that's the answer. You have 8 classes

Comment: Oh i see.. But i don't know how to fix it. I try to 
train_labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(train_labels,8)
But it's not work.....

Comment: `num_of_classes=8`

Comment: OMG , It's work , thank you for that. But i have a question. 
num_of_classes = len(glob('gestures/*')) (number of file). So are another solution instead of num_of_classes=8?
Sorry a lot for my bad English :(